# How to download entire Azure App Service/Logic App?

Tags: azure-functions

In this video [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8x5sBBUP6pM] Chris Anderson mentioned that you can download your whole Azure Function App but didn't say how that can be done. Hearing it prompted me to ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Service Function App and Logic App are two very distinct things. Focusing answer on the Function App part. Please use a separate question for the Logic App.

One simple way is to go to the [Kudu Console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) for your Function App. Then navigate to the Site folder, and click the download (down arrow) button next to the wwwroot folder. This will download a zip with all your function files.

Comment: I had tried that. It just opened a blank window for me. If it works for you, what browser did you use?

Comment: It should work with all browsers. Try Chrome. Also, try copying the URL from the link and pasting it in a new tab as a test.

Comment: I was using IE11. Copying link and pasting into a new tab did work. I'm calling this a bug in Kudu.

Comment: Could be. I don't use IE anymore. Just Chrome and Edge.